# Extracting multiple lines out of band XXE

Tags: ftp, xml, xxe

I was able to extract a line from the `/etc/hostname` file  and also `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-hostname` but I want to extract the content of files with multiple line, such as the aws credentials or `/etc/passwd`

I tried php filter base64 encode but did not work.

I am using ngrok on my local machine so I tried to extract from ftp method but it did not work for me.

How could I extract a file with FTP?

In FTP, I tried to listen on my vps and used https://github.com/lc/230-OOB/blob/master/230.py to listen on ftp port 2122

and I used this payload:

[image]

I did not get any result. But if I replaced `/etc/passwd` with `/etc/hostname` I am able to get the hostname in my logs only

Comment: It's not clear from all this that you know how the python script works or what you are trying to do exactly. This just looks like a "how do I use this exploit?" type question, which is off-topic. We are not a hacking forum. If you have a specific question, we can take a look at it.